# How to get the data off of a ReadyNAS drive?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, data-recovery, readynas

I have a Netgear ReadyNAS Duo network backup system with two drives in it. The data is accessible through the network, but when I remove a drive to get the data off in another computer, it shows that the drive is un formatted. I was thinking that maybe it is encrypted, or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

The question is: How can I get the data off of either of the drives in an external environment?

Comment: What OS did you try reading the drive in? Linux can read an awful lot of formats, and it's possible the drives are in a RAID type setup too.

Comment: @Xen2050 I tried reading them in Windows, but I can try Ubuntu

Comment: Windows really likes to advise formatting anything it can't read - ***don't do it*** (obviously ;-) I found some helpful looking info, posting an A now

Comment: @Xen2050 No luck with Ubuntu :(

Comment: Was the drive detected? Anything in `lsblk`, `blkid`, `gparted`, `gnome-disk-utility`, messages in `dmesg`/ `/var/log/syslog`? Just read other message, keep tryin. It might be possible that the drive is failing too, but I'd expect windows to see something else wrong besides just "unformatted"

Comment: @Xen2050 Sorry, in the above comment, I hadn't tried your answer yet. I meant no luck with just plugging in the drive to Ubuntu :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34855/discussion-between-jo99blackops-and-xen2050).

Answer (score 2):

Apparently a [ReadyNAS can use either](http://www.rnasguide.com/) EXT4 or BTRFS filesystems, and may use a RAID for multiple drives (like yours might).

Windows does not natively read those filesystems (currently), some 3rd party drivers are available, I've found their effectiveness to be mixed.

I found some interesting links with info on reading a non-RAID drive, and most linuxes (linuses? linuxii?) - most any Linux distribution - can read ext4 & btrfs.

This link [Restoring Data from Netgear ReadyNAS Duo Hard Drive](http://firstpersontroubleshooter.blogspot.ca/2011/12/restoring-data-from-netgear-readynas.html) has instructions for non-RAID drives, should be worth a try. It sources [this very very long forum thread](https://community.netgear.com/t5/New-to-ReadyNAS/ReadyNAS-Data-Recovery-VMware-recovery-tool/td-p/651898) as a reference. I'm sure there are RAID instructions available from a regular web search, if required. The basics are:

1. [to 6. on the original link] Get a Linux going that can read your hard drive
2. Here, some newer distributions may already be able to see & mount the hard drive's partitions.

   If your file manager lists devices, it's *possible* that just clicking on the hard drive there *may* mount & open it.

   Easiest way I can think if would be to try running Disks / `gnome-disk-utility` and see if it can mount them with a few clicks. (Disks can also erase or overwrite partitions with a few clicks too, so **BE CAREFUL!**).

   Or `system-config-lvm` is a gui lvm manager, *probably* not required though.
3. **`modprobe fuse`** This command is used to add modules to linux to be able to "talk" to the HDD
4. **`vgscan`** scans all SCSI, IDE and other disk devices on the system looking for LVM physical volumes
5. **`vgchange -ay c`** allows you to change the attribute of the HDD volume groups to "activate" and name the volume group as C
6. **`mkdir /mnt/lvm`** create a mount point for the volume group
7. **`mount -v /dev/c/c /mnt/lvm`** to mount the volume/group. [Original page's command was `ext2fuse /dev/c/c /mnt/lvm` but it's apparently no longer in Ubuntu or Mint or Ubuntu's software repositories (there is a `fuseext2` package & fuseext2 binary...) It would've used the installed ext2fuse utility to support the mounted EXT3 file system. You will notice a slight delay in output until this is displayed:

   > /dev/c/c is to be mounted at /mnt/lvm fuse-ext2 intiailized for device: /dev/c/c block size is 16384

   Once this is displayed, your HDD should be accesible.
8. [Use a file manager/browser to read your files in `/mnt/lvm`]. Or Open another terminal window and enter **`cd /mnt/lvm`**. You should notice a few folders such as Media, Home, etc. If you enter in **`cd media`** then **`ls`**, this will list the files/folders in the Media folder.

Comment: I'll try this right now and keep you posted..

Comment: Ok, I'm stuck at step 7. It says the command "ext2fuse" is not found

Comment: That command wasn't available in Mint either, or in the mint/ubuntu software repos apparently.  Just `mount /dev/c/c /mnt/lvm` should work, it should auto-detect the type, or `-t ext4` (or ext3/ext2, whichever type you've got) should work?

Comment: Most Linux distributions would have the ext* driver available. No need for FUSE or anything the like.

Comment: That's what confused me too, even in 2011 (when the instructions were posted) I'm sure ext2/3/4? was pretty standard. And instructions the last page of the reference thread replaced the fuse command with a plain mount too

Answer (score 2):

I was able to gain read access (I did not require write access and did not seek it) to a ReadyNAS Duo (v1) drive (X-RAID - the two drives were acting redundantly) in Arch Linux by following a process similar to that laid out in [this blogpost](https://jim-st.blogspot.com/2012/07/mouning-readynas-drives-on-x86-systems.html) and [this other blogpost](https://technostuff.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-mount-disk-used-by-readynas.html):

1. `lsblk` (before and after plugging in the drive via USB)
   to identify the path to the device (in my case /dev/sdb)
2. `vgscan` to confirm that `c` was the appropriate drive group.
3. `vgchange -ay c` to activate the `c` drive group.
4. `fuse-ext2 -o allow_other,ro /dev/c/c /mnt/readynas` to mount the disk. I had to use Fuse (`fuse-ext2` from the AUR). The standard mount command returned an error.
5. When finished, unmount the disk: `fusermount -u /mnt/readynas`

Note, however, that I was only able to read the "left" drive (in bay 1) with this process. The "right" drive (bay 2) has no partitions according to `fdisk -l` and does not appear in a `vgscan`.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the disks are in encrypted state, then

1. get **a.s.a.p.** some disks that have at least the same size of the disks in the  NAS (Don't forget - in case of many disks to number them with a pencil etc.)
2. By above stated Linuxes the best are PartitionMagic/Universal Boot CD, Systemrescue CD Linuxes
3. Make of each disk a with the linux shell command ddrescue (or the integrated cloning util, like clonezilla) disk clones - or (Get the disks out of the nas) - put them in a USB3 Cloning station (Price about 30-50 $).**
4. If the disks are readable by the above mentioned rescue Linux, you have luck, otherwise
5. try to use **crypto-LUKS** to decrypt and/or LVM stuff (The steps to mention here are too many, so do a stackoverflow/google search)